# npm http-server downloads PHP files instead of executing them

Tags: php, npm, server, httpserver

As the title says, I'm trying to execute a PHP file on a localhost but it just downloads the file instead. I am using the npm package http-server. I have tried with SimpleHTTPServer from python, but it does the same thing.

I'm running MacOS Mojave. What should I do?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server  I don't see anything about that node's http-server package will do execution of php

Comment: I mean you can, but you shouldn't; you can follow this guide http://promincproductions.com/blog/run-php-script-node-js/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: Configuring php development machine like that would lead to lot confusions, try MAMP or LAMP packages from bitnami. Easy two configure, use and trash.

Answer (score 7):

You can use PHP's [Built-in Webserver](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) with `php -S 127.0.0.1:8080` if this is for development purposes.

Your core issue here is that you're assuming any webserver package will run PHP files, which isn't accurate.

You'll need a webserver with PHP integration or modules, such as NGINX with PHP-FPM, or Apache 2 with mod-cgi